# Explanation of segments, extents, and data blocks

Tags: sql, oracle

Can a simple explanation of segments, extents, and data blocks be provided? Is it necessary for a SQL Developer to understand the concepts of segments, extents, and data blocks?

Comment: [Logical Storage Structures](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/logical-storage-structures.html)

Comment: whats the saying? Knowledge is power.  If you plan on working and growing your career in Oracle, read and understand the basic concepts, structures, and architecture.  [Concepts Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/toc.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link provided in the comment will explain the three concepts in more depth than any user can.

As for whether a developer needs to understand these concepts: no. All these memory concepts are (mostly*) used and tweaked for memory-intense query operations like joins, sorts, etc. Oracle will communicate with the OS to figure out the hardware's page size, etc. to optimize these parameters.

If anything, it's the DBA's job to touch these numbers, and not a developer's. The optimizer will make sure that any query you write will generate a plan that incorporates the physical storage characteristics of the tables and system.